# Firefox Add-On for closing multiple tabs except some

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a Firefox addon, compatible with the latest version, which closes all tabs, except some which I can select. So, if I have 40 Open Tabs, and I want to keep only 3 open, this addon should be able to close the other 37.
Such an addon is: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/close-multiple-tabs/
Unfortunately, this version is not compatible with Firefox 13. Do you know an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without add-ons, you can make use of **App Tabs** to close all but a few. Let's say you have `n` tabs that you want to keep open:

1. **Pin** tabs `Tab[1], Tab[2], Tab[3], ..., Tab[n-1]` by **right-clicking** them and selecting "Pin as App Tab".

   [image: pin]
2. **Right-click** `Tab[n]` and select "Close Other Tabs".

   [image: close]
3. Now, you will only have `n` tabs left *(and any other older pinned tabs)*! **Right-click** each newly pinned tab and select "Unpin Tab" to restore them.

   [image: unpin]

---

### Video Demonstration:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZVye1mjWhI

Answer (score 3):

[How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/select-specific-tab-with-keyboard-hotkey-in-firefox/) has some **Hotkeys:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> activates the leftmost tab.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> will activate each of the tabs in order from left to right.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> will always activate the rightmost tab.

Note that these are specific to the Windows version. Replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Linux, or <kbd>Win</kbd> on the Mac.

[Mutiple Tab Handler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multiple-tab-handler/) may be what are you looking for. Some feature are listed below:

#### Built-in features for selected tabs:

> Close selected tabs
> Close not-selected tabs
> Reload selected tabs
> Duplicate selected tabs
> Pin/unpin selected tabs (Minefield/Firefox 4)
> Move selected tabs to a group (Minefield/Firefox 4)
> Move selected tabs to a new window
> Bookmark selected tabs
> Copy URIs/titles+URIs/HTML links for selected tabs to the clipboard
> Save (download) selected tabs to the local disk

#### Extra features for general tab context menu:

> Close right tabs
> Close left tabs
> Close all tabs include the selected tab
> Close similar tabs (same domain) exclude the selected tab

Comment: Those hotkeys don't work in Firefox 14.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail hmmmmmm so I'm not responsible for that because when I posted this answer these were worked with FF 13, this is not a good reason to down vote.

Comment: @avirk I disagree that _this is not a good reason to down vote_. you should try to keep the answer updated, especially when pointed out by others. The downvote indicates that you *should* update the answer.

Comment: @avirk: I'm pretty sure Firefox has never supported selecting tabs (without extensions).

Comment: Those hotkeys are working for me on a mostly vanilla copy of FF14.01

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail And I'm pretty sure it has, at least since version 3 on Windows, barring an extension blocking it :P. They are listed [on an official Mozilla support page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs).

Comment: @Bob: I see; the support page is using confusing terminology. It's really *activating* the tabs, not *selecting* them (I was thinking) selecting multiple tabs to e.g. close them).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I second Multiple Tabs Handler.

Take a look at the following link too:

11 addons other than TMP to work with Tabs(Described) 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/ChessWriter/tabs/

Comment: Funny, title of that page says `17 add-ons`, the text on that page says `12 add-ons`, your text says `11 add-ons` (but granted, that's 11+ years ago) and there are actually *only 2 add-ons listed* there.